# How to find a pair of the opposite type of connection?

Tags: architecture, client-server

Clients connect to the server. Clients are divided into two types, for example: Male, Female. The type is determined at the time of connection. When a client sends a message that he is ready, we need to find him a pair of the opposite sex. Plus, the woman can refuse such a pair, and then the search continues for both of them.

How to implement this architecture?

Comment: With a computer? Seriously though, you didn't specify programming language, operating system, platform for the clients (web browser, mobile phone, carrier pigeons), or nearly enough information for anyone to help you.

Comment: It seems that you need an additional message for woman to ask her if she agrees to such a pair. But this needs more specification (who is making the decision, what are timeouts, etc.)